# EKF or KF package that fuse IMU and Pressure Sensros data for Velocity estimation?

Tags: ros, sensor-fusion, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Im looking for a ROS package (KF or UKF or EKF) that can fuse IMU and Pressure Sensors data. I would like to have 6x6 estimated Velocity matrices( linear and angular) from the IMU and Pressure sensor data. IMU is 9 DOF ( orientation, angular_velocity and linear_acceleration) and the Pressure. Barometer(pressure sensor data) can be use for the underwater robot as assume the sea (water ) level is same(constant) and the pressure suppose to maintain same value my linear movement of the underwater robot (vehicle). Is it possible to use this package to fuse this IMU and Pressure data to obtain estimated Velocity (linear and angular)?

If no existing ROS package (that serve as velocity observer) and fuse IMU and Pressure data, then any other code or help that I can use and implemented in ROS?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387085/ekf-or-kf-package-that-fuse-imu-and-pressure-sensros-data-for-velocity-estimation?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2021-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at this ROS package : http://wiki.ros.org/hector_localization

> The hector_localization stack is a collection of packages, that provide the full 6DOF pose of a robot or platform. It uses various sensor sources, which are fused using an Extended Kalman filter. Acceleration and angular rates from an inertial measurement unit (IMU) serve as primary measurements. The usage of other sensors is application-dependent. The hector_localization stack currently supports GPS, magnetometer, barometric pressure sensors and other external sources that provide a geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance message via the poseupdate topic.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-09-25**:
thanks. Ok will  check  it

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-09-29**:
how to set up the launch file to use IMU and Pressure sensors?

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-29**:
I recommend to start another question as per the FAQ guidance. Thank you

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-09-29**:
I have done it. Please check it